# Install PHP 5.2 on CentOS 5.9: undefined symbol php_sig_jpg

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php

I have installed PHP 5.2 from source (we're moving some sites that require 5.2, unfortunately) to a CentOS box. PHP is compiled from source, but when I try to start apache I get the following error:

```
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: 
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf: 
Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so into server: 
/etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: php_sig_jpg
```

I have libpng, libpng-devel, gd, gd-devel, libjpeg, and libjpeg-devel all installed as well but can't figure out what could be causing this.

**Edit:** adding the contents of /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: is this module is present in your apache module directory /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it's there

Comment: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf , please check for syntax on line 1.

Comment: Doesn't look like there are any syntax errors. I'll add that to the question too

Comment: Just use 5.3 if you can. Nearly all PHP scripts which "need" 5.2 will work fine on 5.3.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't for whatever reason. I did find a "solution": I was apparently trying to install php5.2.12. When I compiled php5.2.17 it works. :|

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are missing some part of the gd library.  Check out what php/gd-related packages you have with this:

```
rpm -qa| grep -iE php\gd |sort
```

If you have not already, you may want to use the source RPMs to build custom RPM packages.  This is often a less-brittle way to build and deploy from source on RedHat-based distros.